# Imbedding Theorems between Besov Spaces and space of continuos functions on the unit circle

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, function-spaces, besov-spaces

I'll try to be brief.

Let us consider the Besov Space $B^{1/p}_{p, p}(\mathbb{T})$, where $1\leq p<\infty $ and $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle in the complex plane. I would like to know for which  range of $\alpha$ one has a continuos imbedding of $C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{T})$ into $B^{1/p}_{p, p}(\mathbb{T})$.

In other words, what are the conditions on $\alpha$ so that the map:

$$\iota:C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{T}) \to B^{1/p}_{p, p}(\mathbb{T})$$

is continuous and bounded?

Any references are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: to be clear, the space $C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{T})$ denotes the space of functions which are $[\alpha]-$differentiable, where $[\alpha]$ is the integer part of $\alpha$, and the all derivatives up to order $[\alpha]$ are Hoelderian with exponent $\alpha-[\alpha]$.